# PHP - Print empty <td> within foreach

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've two arrays:

```
$arrInfoComment;
```

Array contains ID of commented user and Comment. (For instance: 2 comments)

```
$arrInfoExpert;
```

Array contains ID of users. (3 users)

I'm looping arrays with foreach and printing them out of loop.
How can I put an empty `<td>-</td>` if user not commented?

```
$expComm = '';
foreach($arrInfoComment as $comExperts){
    foreach($arrInfoExpert as $ExpertID){
        if($comExperts['ID'] == $ExpertID){
            $expComm .= '<td><p>'.$comExperts['COMMENT'].'</p></td>';
        }
    }
}
echo $expComm;
```

Structure of $arrInfoComment

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [COMMENT] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vestibulum elementum libero, at laoreet risus sodales at. .
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [COMMENT] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vestibulum elementum libero, at laoreet risus sodales at. .
        )
)
```

Structure of $arrInfoExpert

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

Attached screenshot of last result that I want to achieve.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Post your array structures

Comment: @Uchiha posted structure of arrays

Comment: do you want the haed of table as sorted list of users of $arrInfoExpert? or unsorted?

Comment: @splash58 yeap as sorted list of users $arrInfoExpert

Comment: I think it is helpfull to remake `$arrInfoComment` as `id =>comment`, or build array `id => key in $arrInfoComment` to avoid repeating  of search

Comment: @splash58 well, how to do?

Comment: I'm still busy, if no one writes, after half an hour i'll write

Comment: @splash58 thanks, but Ajon solved. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now see the issue.  You should flip the order of the foreach loops.  First loop over the experts then loop over the comments.

try this?

```
$expComm = '';
foreach($arrInfoExpert as $expertID){
    $comment = '-';
    foreach($arrInfoComment as $comExperts){
        if ($comExperts['ID'] == $expertID){
            $comment = '<p>'.$comExperts['COMMENT'].</p>;
            break;
        }
    }
    $expComm .= "<td>$comment</td>";
}
```

Comment: a little bit closer. But your solution prints 6 <td>s. 2 filled and 4 empty. Like this: - - comment - comment -.

Comment: This solution prints exactly 1 td for each Expert in $arrInfoExpert.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: did you see the screenshot?

Comment: @Refresh Yes, I saw what was happening.  That is why I updated my answer.  The above answer iterates over the experts then grabs the corresponding comment.  If there isn't a comment it prints the empty `<td>-</td>` like you requested.  Did you try my change?

Comment: yes i tried your refreshed solution and it's worked! Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $expComm .= '<td><p>'.(!empty($comExperts['COMMENT']) ? $comExperts['COMMENT'] : '-').'</p></td>';
```

you can use ternary operator for it,if comment will be empty then print ' - ' otherwise comment

Comment: You should explain the answer so that the OP know what it is doing.

Comment: Prints without empty <td>.  If user_1 not commented then user_2's comment shifted left to column of user_1.

Comment: If what you really want is to fix the issue with empty cells not being displayed, you can change that by setting `<table style="empty-cells: show">`

Comment: @Havenard no buddy, here is sth diff issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
foreach($arrInfoComment as $comExperts)
    {
        foreach($arrInfoExpert as $ExpertID)
        {
            if($comExperts['ID'] == $ExpertID)
            {
                if(empty($comExperts['COMMENT']))
                {
                    $expComm .= '<td><p> &mdash; </p></td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $expComm .= '<td><p>'.$comExperts['COMMENT'].'</p></td>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $expComm;
```

Comment: prints without empty <td>. I think, we've problem with condition, because $arrInfoComment has 2 elements but $arrInfoExpert 3.

Comment: what are the veris you need to check??

Comment: look to ajon 's solution it's little bit closer but it prints additional empty <td>, so here is result screenshot of ajon's solution: http://s21.postimg.org/mu13tl2xj/image.jpg. So is it possible to get rid of this <td>'s?

Comment: you want remove extra `<td>` ??

Comment: yes, but i've already solve it. But, will also appriciate your solution